# Error de compilación en Heroku con Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, heroku

Hola intento hacer un deploy en heroku y me sale este error:

> [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
> remote:        [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
> remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_243489b3/src/main/java/com/gortiz/proyectexample/service/productService.java:[7,8] class ProductService is public, should be declared in a file named ProductService.java
> remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_243489b3/src/main/java/com/gortiz/proyectexample/service/providerService.java:[7,8] class ProviderService is public, should be declared in a file named ProviderService.java
> remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_243489b3/src/main/java/com/gortiz/proyectexample/service/serviceImp/serviceProviderImpl.java:[15,8] class ServiceProviderImpl is public, should be declared in a file named ServiceProviderImpl.java
> remote:        [INFO] 3 errors
> remote:        [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
> remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> remote:        [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
> remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> remote:        [INFO] Total time:  14.496 s
> remote:        [INFO] Finished at: 2020-12-03T11:30:45Z
> remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> remote:        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project proyect-example: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
> remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_243489b3/src/main/java/com/gortiz/proyectexample/service/productService.java:[7,8] class ProductService is public, should be declared in a file named ProductService.java
> remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_243489b3/src/main/java/com/gortiz/proyectexample/service/providerService.java:[7,8] class ProviderService is public, should be declared in a file named ProviderService.java
> remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_243489b3/src/main/java/com/gortiz/proyectexample/service/serviceImp/serviceProviderImpl.java:[15,8] class ServiceProviderImpl is public, should be declared in a file named ServiceProviderImpl.java
> remote:        [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
> remote:        [ERROR]
> remote:        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> remote:        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> remote:        [ERROR]
> remote:        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
> remote:        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
> remote:
> remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
> remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
> remote:        please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
> remote:
> remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
> remote:
> remote:  !     Push failed
> remote:  !
> remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: d382c9e57a10b917ec7cf8bdb5a4a121a46052bc
> remote:  !
> remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version d382c9e57a10b917ec7cf8bdb5a4a121a46052bc
> remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
> remote:  !
> remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
> remote:  !
> remote:  !     git push heroku :main
> remote:  !
> remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
> remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
> remote:
> remote: Verifying deploy...

Comment: Le lo que te pone el error, te está diciendo que las clases ProductService, ProviderService y ProviderImpl son públicas y tienen que tener un nombre de archivo igual, incluyendo las mayúsculas en su sitio, y tus nombres de archivo son productService.java, providerService.java y providerImpl.java, renombra estos archivos poniendo las mayúsculas en su sitio :)

Comment: Gracias mi proyecto estaba bien escrito solo que en el github no